# Image upload won't work on PHP CLOUD

Tags: image

I'm using www.phpcloud.com as a server for my application. I'm testing it so I can also determine the limitation of this application. It is free and fast. Now I have a problem. My code is not working. I can't upload photo/image. I've used the ajax style upload but it won't work. I have can it to the name way, but it also don't work.

here is the code:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['PF']['tmp_name'],"images/".$_FILES['PF']['name']);
```

The $_FILES['PF']['name'] have a value and the value is the image/photo that I upload.

anyone who have experience this and solve it? Or anyone who can help me please?.

THanks,
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check if the upload succeeded? Just because you get the original filename in PHP doesn't mean it did:

```
if ($_FILES['PF']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['PF']['error']);
}
```

The error codes are defined [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Beyond that, never ever use the user-provided filename blindly in a filesystem operation as you are. It is trivial for a malicious user to embed a path into that file and your code would allow them to scribble on any file on your server which the webserver userID has write access to. e.g. `...['file'] = '../../../../../../../../etc/passwd'`.

Comment: Hi there,

It successful upload the file. Since the value of $_FILES['PF']['error'] is 0

Comment: And the return value of move_uploaded_file? If it's boolean false, the move failed, which usually means there's a permissions problem, or the target directory does not exist.

Comment: how to check the value of move_uploaded_file if it's true or false ? I think it's false becuase I place the move_uploaded_file on a if condition like this if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['PF']['tmp_name'],"images/".$_FILES['PF']['name'])) {  } else {  $_FILES['PF']['error'] }

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you very much! problem is permission problem.